# Implement Drag Sort in Oracle ADF

Tags: jquery, oracle-adf

I want to implement the drag sort (eg: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid) in Oracle ADF.

The below code I have tried in ADF:

```
<af:panelList rows="6" maxColumns="3" id="sortable1"
                      listStyle="list-style-type:none" >
         <af:forEach varStatus="vs" begin="1" end="17">
          <af:panelList rows="6" maxColumns="3" styleClass="thumbnail" id="test"
                          listStyle="list-style-type:none">
         <af:panelGroupLayout layout="vertical"
                                               styleClass="thumbnail" id="pgl4">
           <af:outputText id="ot2" value="#{vs.index} #{vs.count} #{vs.begin}"/> 
           </af:panelGroupLayout>
            </af:panelList>
          </af:forEach>
</af:panelList>
```

The below is  jquery for sort:

```
<af:resource type="javascript" source="/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"/>
        <af:resource type="javascript" source="/js/jquery-ui.js"/>
        <trh:script id="sx4">
           $(function () {
              $("#sortable1").sortable();
              $("#sortable1").disableSelection();
          });
        </trh:script>
```

But I am not able to do the drag sort. How can I implement the drag sort?

Comment: Maybe a 'bit' more information? Like a question or something...

Comment: I have mentioned link above (http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid). The same thing I need to covert to oracle adf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Panel Dash Board for achieving the requirement of dragsort.

The code I used is below one:

```
<af:panelDashboard id="pd1">
                          <af:forEach begin="1" end="5" step="1" varStatus="vs"
                                      var="v">
                            <af:panelBox text="#{vs.index}">
                              <af:componentDragSource/>
                              <af:panelGroupLayout layout="vertical"
                                                   styleClass="thumbnail"
                                                   id="pgl10">
                                <af:outputText id="ot8"
                                               value="#{vs.index} #{vs.count} #{vs.begin}"/>
                              </af:panelGroupLayout>
                            </af:panelBox>
                          </af:forEach>
                        </af:panelDashboard>
```

The component  will do the drag sort of the items (panel box).
No java script file is required. It will simply do the same thing as drag sort (eg: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid) in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend against using jQuery to adjust the DOM while ADF is in use.  ADF does some strange things to the DOM and jQuery does equally strange but incompatible things to the DOM.  Combining them is a recipe for problems.

The thing you might want to look at is using the Drag/Drop source/target interfaces for ADF.  Those might help you out, but I strongly suspect this is not possible.